# How to use a specific row to modify the others in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given the following dataframe

```
id | value
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 4
```

I want to divide all value by the value of reference : the value associated with id 1

I've come up with :

```
df.cache()

val ref = df
  .filter($"id" === 1)
  .withColumnRenamed("value", "ref")

df
  .crossJoin(broadcast(ref))
  .withColumn("div", $"value" / $"ref)
```

Pro :

- avoid `collect()`, so data are not sent to the spark driver.
- use `cache()` to avoid to compute 2 times the input `DataFrame`.

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

> use cache() to avoid to compute 2 times the input DataFrame.

This is not correct. cache like all other spark operation is laze and will not evaluate unless some action is called upon. so when you do

```
val ref = df
 .filter($"id" === 1)
 .withColumnRenamed("value", "ref")

df
.crossJoin(broadcast(ref))
.withColumn("div", $"value" / $"ref)
```

and eventually call save 2 operations will be evaluated simultaneously. If you really want to cache the data immediately you need to call some action on the cached data

```
df.count
```

may be .